# Serving mixed filenames with send_from_directory() errors out

Tags: python

In an html form i have a user selecting a filename, which then i tried to send to his browser. Here is the code:

```
filename = request.form.get('filename')
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

return send_from_directory(filepath, filename)
```

If the filename selected is in english characters it gets send the user, but, if it contained a mix of english + greek chars it gives a `bad request` i tried to encode `filename.encode("utf-8") but then NO files are being served.

Comment: What is your python version? Because I think python 3.x use utf-8.

Comment: My Python version is v3.6.5

Comment: You can see from this link, it shouldn't be problem. https://jktauber.com/articles/python-unicode-ancient-greek/

Comment: I looked at the link but the encode("utf-8") doesn't help me because if i encode 'filename' then i'm NOT able to download it. Please show me in code what do you suggest please.

Comment: "In Python 3, a literal string is assumed to be a string of Unicode characters. ....assume a UTF-8 encoding by default."  You don't need do something. Your problem can be another thing. Please add full error.

Comment: The error presented when trying to download files with mixed letters is this: `Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` while if i select filenames with only english characters they download nicely.

Comment: If you think it is related filename, add print after filename. You can see what it takes. If it doesn't have problem, you need debugging. You can use pdb package. And link shows how you use it: https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/

Comment: When i print the filename it is displayed in the browser correctly though. I just dont understand why the corresponding file doesnt get downloaded.

Comment: Also i would be gratefull if you showed me how to enable error logginf output to the browser so i dont have to login via ssh all the time.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't. This are related html and django/flask (or what you use). You can close this question, and it would be helpful asking more detailed question with new tags.

Comment: Enabling detailed logging reveals this: `ValueError: unicode object contains non latin-1 characters` Can you help?

Comment: This question is missing the full traceback.

Comment: No traceback when used as `return send_from_directory(filepath, filename)` just being displayed in the browser this `Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

Answer (score 0):

```
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

return send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )
```

The above workd well for english filenames but returns:

```
Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

When filename contains mixed letters.
How to make it work with *every* filename ?!